# Display image based on combobox item selection in wpf

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

I have one combo box in which I have some items like:

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3

Corresponding every item there is image like item1 has image img1.jpg, item2 has image img2.jpg and item3 has image img3.jpg. When we select item from combox it will show their corresponding image in label.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of my question and here it's:

```
<xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageMVVM_Learning"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:EnumToImageConverter x:Key="conv"/>
</Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox x:Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=combo,Path=SelectedValue,Converter={StaticResource conv}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Do this in your viewmodel class:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public class EnumToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            switch ((MyEnum)value)
            {
                case MyEnum.A:
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\A.png", UriKind.Relative));
                case MyEnum.B:
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\B.png", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\A.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Readers please note: the XML snippet above was deliberately damaged in an effort to get it to render on _Stack Overflow_. I've repaired it as best I can (using the code formatting tools provided) but it would be worth checking elsewhere as to whether it is correct. Edits to correct it would be welcome.